# mysql FIND_IN_SET equivalent to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, equivalent, find-in-set

```
select * 
from folder f,uploads u 
where u.id=f.folderId 
and FIND_IN_SET('8', '15,9,13,27')
```

Please tell to me equivalent to predefind or userdefined postgresql  function

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6363756/477878) may work (and actually be faily efficient)

Comment: i am giving example only the actual query:      select * from folder f,uploads u where u.id=f.folderId and FIND_IN_SET('8', another_column);     This is mysql query. I want only for postgresql. Is there any function available.

Comment: Which PG version are you using?

Comment: What data type is this `another_column`? Please edit your question and show the definition of the table (as `create table`) , some sample data and the expected output

Comment: FIND_IN_SET(int, text) datatype, another_column is text datatype

Comment: The PostgreSQL way would be to not use the CSV-in-a-column anti-pattern at all, if you need all those values in a single column then you'd use an array (probably `int[]`) and `= any(...)` or other array operations.

Comment: postgresql version 9.4

Answer (score 17):

You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place, but you can do something like this:

```
select * 
from folder f
  join uploads u ON u.id = f.folderId 
where '8' = ANY (string_to_array(some_column,','))
```

`string_to_array()` converts a string into a real array based on the passed delimiter

Comment: @Mayhem: there are some best practices for designing a relational database. Normalization is one of them. And storing only atomic values is the first step in normalization. Storing (comma) delimited values in a column violates this most basic principle. If you want to ignore 30 years of design guidelines, then by all means do it.

Comment: Again it depends on the dataset.. seeing one row or a extract does not show their full dataset. There are many cases where having a column per item can be wrong.. specifically if the amount of csv is an unknown length... if some rows have 10 columns and in the rare case it could be 100 or 1000.. would you really have a table with 1000 columns? When 99% of rows are only 10 items.. never assume... if you think boxed.. you end up being in a box.. anyway the point stands that real world data does not always follow rules in paper.. and storing a string of csv in a single field does not violate it.

Comment: It seems that in Postgres ANY does not respect the order of elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345219/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-order-or-array-when-using-any-in-postgres-query unlike MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813884/how-do-you-keep-the-order-using-select-where-in

Comment: @CiroSantilliПутлерКапут六四事: not sure what you mean with "preserve order". The `ANY` operator just tests if the value on the left hand side occurs *any*where in the array on the right hand side. The query has no `order by` so there is no implied sort order in the result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813884/how-do-you-keep-the-order-using-select-where-in suggests that mysql FIND_IN_SET returns rows in the order of the arguments given, so it seems that postgres ANY is slightly different from mysql FIND_IN_SET in that sense.

Comment: If a query does not have an `ORDER BY`, then the database is free to return the rows in any order it likes. _If_ there is a certain order you see without an ORDER BY this is a coincidence. The **only** way to get a *guaranteed* sort order, is to use ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

The `FIND_IN_SET()` function in MySQL applies - not surprisingly - to sets. The equivalent of a MySQL `SET` in PostgreSQL is the [`enum` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html), with some minor differences in implementation.

The `FIND_IN_SET()` function returns the index of an item in the set, or 0 if not present in the set. That is logically non-sensical: ["a set is an abstract data type that can store certain values, without any particular order, and no repeated values"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)). PostgreSQL has no built-in way to find the order of an item in an `enum` type, it doesn't even have a way to find out *if* a string is also an item in an `enum` type. And that is just how it should be.

If you are working with "sets" of strings in a less restricted sense, you probably want to use a `text[]` data type for your column. Your query then becomes, assuming you test just for the presence of a value in the array:

```
SELECT * 
FROM folder f
JOIN uploads u ON u.id = f.folderId 
WHERE '8' = ANY (text_array_column);
```

If you want the specific index of `'8'` in the text array column you should specify in your question what you want to do with it; with the current information a better answer is impossible.

Comment: Actually `find_in_set` applies to string values that contain a comma separated list of values. It has nothing to do with enums

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * 
       from folder f,uploads u 
          where u.id=f.folderId and '8' in('15','9','13','27')
```